# AWS SDK suddenly stopped working on React native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk-nodejs

So i am facing a very weird issue. I have a react native app that was working fine until yesterday night. Suddenly then my aws s3 connections stopped working. We had made no changes in the code to that code in 2 months which is why im confused.

Here is my CloudService.js

```js
import React ,{useState} from 'react';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

export const S3_BUCKET_CAROUSEL ='carouselnews';
export const S3_BUCKET_ADVISORS = 'advisorsdata';
const REGION ='ap-south-1';


AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'xxxxxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxx'
})

export const getCarouselData = () => {
    const bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: { Bucket: S3_BUCKET_CAROUSEL},
        region: REGION,
    })

    const S3_URL = `https://${S3_BUCKET_CAROUSEL}.s3.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/`


    return bucket.listObjects().promise();
}

export const getS3URL = (bucket) => {
    return `https://${bucket}.s3.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/`
}
```

Calling it in my Home.js like this:
(Gets executed inside useEffect but i tried moving it outside into a button too)

```js
getCarouselData()
    .then(data => {
      if (data) {
        var s3_url = getS3URL(S3_BUCKET_CAROUSEL);
        var items = data.Contents;
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (index > 5) {
            return;
          }
          setcarouselItems(oldArray => [
            ...oldArray,
            {
              id: index + 1,
              url: `${s3_url}${item.Key}`,
            },
          ]);
        });
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        setcarouselLoaded(true);
      }, 4000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(zz => {
      console.log("whatttt")
    })
```

Basically when the method runs, it does not return anything. Doesnt go in the catch either and i tried putting try catch inside, even there nothing happens

I checked my credential keys in AWS IAM to see if theres a problem there but according to that my keys were not used after last night atall!
[image]

Some little info, when i try to print just the bucket object, it does give a result saying that there is some interaction going on with AWS i think

Heres the response when i do `console.log(bucket)`

```js
{"CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE": [Function CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE], "MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE": [Function EVENTS_BUBBLE], "_clientId": 27, "_events": {"apiCall": [[Function CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE]], "apiCallAttempt": [[Function EVENTS_BUBBLE]]}, "config": {"apiVersion": null, "apiVersions": {}, "clientSideMonitoring": false, "computeChecksums": true, "convertResponseTypes": true, "correctClockSkew": false, "credentialProvider": null, "credentials": {"accessKeyId": "AKIAXERRWBISWIDH64XH", "expireTime": null, "expired": false, "refreshCallbacks": [Array], "sessionToken": undefined}, "customUserAgent": null, "dynamoDbCrc32": true, "endpoint": "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", "endpointCacheSize": 1000, "endpointDiscoveryEnabled": undefined, "hostPrefixEnabled": true, "httpOptions": {"timeout": 120000}, "logger": null, "maxRedirects": 10, "maxRetries": undefined, "paramValidation": true, "params": {"Bucket": "carouselnews"}, "region": "ap-south-1", "retryDelayOptions": {}, "s3BucketEndpoint": false, "s3DisableBodySigning": true, "s3ForcePathStyle": false, "s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint": "legacy", "s3UseArnRegion": undefined, "signatureCache": true, "signatureVersion": "v4", "sslEnabled": true, "stsRegionalEndpoints": "legacy", "systemClockOffset": 0, "useAccelerateEndpoint": false, "useDualstackEndpoint": false, "useFipsEndpoint": false}, "endpoint": {"host": "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", "hostname": "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", "href": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/", "path": "/", "pathname": "/", "port": 443, "protocol": "https:"}, "isGlobalEndpoint": false}
```

The network call for the aws call:
[image]

Comment: is `getCarouselData` being called? Is the code in `finally` being executed? If yes, then either the `then` or the `catch` clause will be executed, no matter what. But depending on the timeout in the AWS SDK (default = 2min) it might be quite a while until the `listObject` requests fails, if there is a problem with the network  ... Have you tried inspecting your network traffic with the developer tools?

Comment: yes its being called, i tried putting a log inside and its being executed.. also the code in finally is not getting executed either..i assumed the same that the request will timeout and ill get the response from finally but it did not happen. I will try to check the network call though, it slipped my mind.. will update after checking

Comment: @derpirscher I checked the debugger and found the network call but the data sent is null and has no response data. I've attached it at the end of my original post

Comment: Hey i got it working, the emulator had issues, just wiped data and restarted it and it worked. The code was fine, thanks for the help though man